# quasi-PCA reconstruction of the matrix by orthogonal basis

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, svd, matrix-decomposition

Let's say I have a "data" matrix $X$ of $N$ rows and $p$ cols with $N \gg p$. Now PCA with $L$ components can be formulated as

$$
X_L = \underset{Y:rank(Y) = L}{\text{argmin}}  ||X- Y||^2_F, 
$$

where $Y$ is taken to be an $L$-dimensional approximation of $X$.

It's known that $X_L = X W_L W^T_L$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Dimensionality_reduction) e.g.) where $W_L$ is $p \times L$ matrix of first $L$ principal components of $X$. However, suppose I instead want to choose an arbitrary orthonormal basis $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_p$ and construct $W_L = [w_1 w_2 \dots w_L]$ for $L = 1, 2, \dots, p$. Am I guaranteed that the "unexplained" variance $||X- X_L||^2_F$ is going to monotonically decrease in $L$, the number of dimensions I retain, if the matrix $W_L$ is built iteratively (that is, if we fixed $w_1$ we may only add $w_2, w_3$ etc., but never throw away $w_1$)? It feels like the answer is "yes", but maybe I'm missing something? It definitely decreases from $L = 1$ to $L = p$.

Comment: Please see here for a nice answer - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4479855/980581